# AngularJS $rootScope array of user-entered objects getting overwritten by last entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Below is the AngularJS application with run block used for rootScope initializing of some arrays, service and controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngAnimate','ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('myApp').run(function($rootScope) {
$rootScope.stages = [];
$rootScope.stage = {
        level : 1,
        field1 : 'myValue1',
        field2 : 'myValue2',
        field3 : {
            field4 : 'myValue4',
            field5 : {
                field6 : 'myValue6'
            }
        }
};
});
angular.module('myApp').service('stagesService', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        stages: function () {
            return $rootScope.stages;
        },
        addStage: function () {
            console.log("Inside stagesService.addStage");
            console.log($rootScope.stage);
            $rootScope.stages.push($rootScope.stage);
            /*angular.forEach($rootScope.stages, function() {
                this.push($rootScope.stage);
            });*/
            return true;
        }
    };
});
angular.module('myApp').controller('StageFormModalCtrl', [ '$rootScope', '$scope', 'stagesService', '$filter', function($rootScope, $scope, stagesService, $filter) {
$scope.addStage = function() {
            stagesService.addStage();
            console.log("Added Stage : "+stagesService.getStage(1).level + ","+stagesService.getStage(1).query + ","+ stagesService.getStage(1).expectedfilename);          
            $scope.stages(); //<-- updating rootscope stages Array each time a new stage is added
        }
}
$scope.stages = function() {
var currstages = stagesService.stages();
console.log(currstages);
}
}]);
```

The HTML div code corresponding to the modal form for submitting stage inputs and corresponding to the StageFormModalCtrl controller is as follows:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="stageModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1"
                aria-labelledby="stageModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="stageModallabel">Enter stage</h4>               
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form name="stageInputForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" 
                    ng-controller="StageFormModalCtrl">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="level">Enter Level</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10"> 

                        <input type="number" string-to-number min="1" step="1" name="level" id="level" class="form-control"
                        ng-model="stage.level"/>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="field1">Enter field1</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10"> 

                        <textarea row="4" cols="50" name="field1" id="field1" class="form-control" 
                        ng-model="stage.field1"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="field2">Enter field2</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">

                        <input type="text" name="field2" id="field2" class="form-control"
                        ng-model="stage.field2"/>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                        data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addStage()">Add</button>
                </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

The stage form inputs are data-bind to the $rootScope.stage fields and once the "Add" button is clicked, the stages are supposed to be added based on whatever input is provided in the form.

But while pushing multiple stages into $rootScope.stages the last stage is overwriting all the previous stages. For example,

First I pushed `level=1, field1="X", field2="Y"`

```
$rootScope.stages = [{level : 1, field1 : X, field2 : Y}]
```

Then I pushed `level=2, field1="W", field2="Z"`

```
$rootScope.stages = [{level : 2, field1 : W, field2 : Z},
                     {level : 2, field1 : W, field2 : Z}
]
```

instead of

```
$rootScope.stages = [{level : 1, field1 : X, field2 : Y},
                     {level : 2, field1 : W, field2 : Z}
]
```

Any idea on why this weird overwriting is happening?

Comment: As a side note, it is a bad practice to use `$rootScope` for this kind of stuff.

Comment: @Mistalis: This is my first project on AngularJS and would appreciate if you could suggest the best practice

Comment: @Mistalis: I needed multiple controllers to share some data. One controller CTRL1 is the main app, the other modal controller CTRL2 handling the form elements used to input data to modify the DOM handled by CTRL1. So I used rootScope variables and service. Is there any other way to execute a similar scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using javascript references for `$scope.stage`, and even when you push a new "object" into stages, its an updated reference, meaning that the previous object updates its value also. 
Try wrapping

```
$rootScope.stages.push($rootScope.stage)
```

to

```
$rootScope.stages.push(angular.copy($rootScope.stage));
```

Comment: Great mate! It worked. You'r right ! I will surely check references

Comment: But any idea how the previous stages already added are getting modified ? I presume for each form submission, the addStage is getting called once

Comment: It is because your data models is using the same scope references. Updating this scope model (even when pushed into arrays), will update all references. One solution is to make a form 'submit' action, than sends you values to a defined function. Here you create a new object with the values recieved from the form and push this object into your array - then clear/reset your form values.

Answer (score 1):

Try no $rootScope example:

```
angular.module('myApp').service('stagesService', function() {
    var stages = [];
    return {
        getStages: function () {
            return stages;
        },
        addStage: function (stage) {
            stages.push(stage);
            return true;
        }
    };
});
```

see demo here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rrrobin/axq52kyb/)

Comment: Tried initializing the array in service block but not working ! I would go with the first answer. Thanks

Comment: not sure abt factory. am using service shared across controllers and wasn't working. will have to try with factory. Will check and let know